# Unable to rebuild apk with apktool kali linux

Tags: linux, apk, rebuild, apktool, zipalign

hello guys  failed to recompile an apk with apktool
this is the error log image:

[image]

I did all those commands:

```
apt-get install zipalign
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

and I also already have jdk 10
but still error. Also I delete apktool and reinstalled, but same error. I don't know ho to fix.

Comment: I thought `apktool` was abandoned. I think there was a pseudo-fork and now another tool is used instead. (That was my experience back in 2012 or so. We ended up writing our own tool because there were too many problems with `apktool`). This is probably a better question for [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Try Using [APK Easy Tool](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10jOplY_wnT_47UneXU7use0WBFWNBYxZ) instead for binding your payload to existing apk file.

Old methods i have mentioned before are not working anymore. you can check history for them if you still insist.

Answer (score 1):

i did this command and it worked

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I got `unable to rebuild apk with apktool` error when using `msfvenom`. The problem was that the `apk` file resists the injection, so I tried with another one and it works.

Try another `apk` file, it may work.